# Want to replace/overwrite zero in a text box by a value from excel

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

My application generates a zero in a textbox automatically. I want to replace/overwrite the zero by a value from my excel by sendkeys. I have already used replace, Control+a, double click even clear. But unfortunately did not work. Any help will be appreciated.

HTML

```
<td class="ui-panelgrid-cell" role="gridcell">
<label id="createShipmentForm2:j_idt368" class="ui-outputlabel ui-widget label-black-13-400 mandatoryField" for="createShipmentForm2:totalDeclaredValue" style="margin-left:20px;">
<br/>
<input id="createShipmentForm2:totalDeclaredValue" class="ui-inputfield ui-inputtext ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all custom-input-field ui-state-hover" type="text" aria-required="true" style="width:260px;margin-left:20px;" onblur="PrimeFaces.ab({s:"createShipmentForm2:totalDeclaredValue",e:"blur",f:"createShipmentForm2",p:"createShipmentForm2:totalDeclaredValue"});" onchange="PrimeFaces.bcn(this,event,[function(event){PrimeFaces.ab({s:"createShipmentForm2:totalDeclaredValue",e:"change",f:"createShipmentForm2",p:"createShipmentForm2:totalDeclaredValue"});},function(event){PrimeFaces.ab({s:"createShipmentForm2:totalDeclaredValue",e:"change",f:"createShipmentForm2",p:"createShipmentForm2:totalDeclaredValue",u:"createShipmentForm2:insurancetextbox2"});}])" value="0" name="createShipmentForm2:totalDeclaredValue" role="textbox" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false"/>
</td>
```

Code

```
//To store Auto generated value of TDV

    String autogeneratedTDV=driver.findElement(By.id("createShipmentForm2:totalDeclaredValue")).getAttribute("value");
    excel.printoutput(0, row, 2, autogeneratedTDV);

    Thread.sleep(5000);

    //To change the value of Total Declared value field

    String TDV=excel.getNumericData(1, row, 31);

    if (TDV!="")
    {
    driver.findElement(By.id("createShipmentForm2:totalDeclaredValue")).sendKeys(Keys.HOME,Keys.chord(Keys.SHIFT,Keys.END),TDV);
    }
    else
    {

    Thread.sleep(5000);
    //driver.findElement(By.id("createShipmentForm2:totalDeclaredValue")).clear();

    Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
    builder.doubleClick(driver.findElement(By.id("createShipmentForm2:totalDeclaredValue"))).perform();

    //String selectAll=Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,"a");
    //driver.findElement(By.id("createShipmentForm2:totalDeclaredValue")).sendKeys(selectAll);
    Thread.sleep(8000);
    driver.findElement(By.id("createShipmentForm2:totalDeclaredValue")).sendKeys(excel.getNumericData(0, row, 2));

    }
```

Comment: Hi, Can anybody help me on this? I am still stuck!